# How can I pass multiple args to a std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've got the following code (I'm newbie in thread's world) and I don't know why it doesn't work because I'd seen that the correct way to pass args to threads is exactly as I'd do...
So if someone can help with this, and also maybe one of your can recommend to me some toturials or some content about threads in c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector.hpp>
#include <functional>

void gotoxy(short, short);
void printAt(const char*, eestl::vector<int>&, short, short);

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    eestl::vector<int> Odd{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
    eestl::vector<int> Even{ 0,2,4,6,8 };
    const char* odd_p = "Odd values: ";
    short odd_x = 2;
    short odd_y = 3; 
    const char* even_p = "Even values: ";
    short even_x = 2;
    short even_y = 13;
    std::thread t1{ printAt, odd_p, Odd, odd_x, odd_y};
    std::thread t2{ printAt, even_p, Even, even_x, even_y };

    t1.join(); 
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}

void gotoxy(short x, short y) {
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void printAt(const char* msg, eestl::vector<int>& v, short x = 0, short y = 0) {
    static std::mutex m;
    gotoxy(x, y);
    printf("%s", msg);
    for (auto a : v) {
        m.lock();
        printf("%d, ", a);
        Sleep(1000);
        m.unlock();
    }
}
```

And also if someone is asking for the "vector.hpp" is my own implementation of a vector and the problem is not there because I'de can replace the eestl::vector by std::vector and the error is the same...

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Try `std::thread t1{ printAt, odd_p, std::ref(Odd), odd_x, odd_y};` Better still, have `printAt` take `v` parameter by const reference - you are not modifying it.

Comment: Recommendation: If you are aren't providing something and it's not necessary, edit it out of your [mcve]. It just distracts from the problem and usually becomes more trouble than it's worth. If you need a reference there, you can probably get the same effect with an `int`. And if the problem goes away, well, you learned something about the problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thx it actually works c:

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Damn, now the OP can't accept your answer, because you posted it in the comments section :(

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference.com's `std::thread` constructor page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread):

> If a reference argument needs to be passed to the thread function, it has to be wrapped (e.g. with `std::ref` or `std::cref`).

That is:

```
std::thread t1{ printAt, odd_p,  std::ref(Odd),  odd_x,  odd_y  };
std::thread t2{ printAt, even_p, std::ref(Even), even_x, even_y };
```